# magento 2 : logo image file could not be selected / uploaded

Tags: magento2, admin, image, php-7.2, file-uploader

In `content > design > configuration` theme , I try to **upload new logo** by click on the **Upload button**. However, after select the image from PC, the **ajax icon** only spin a couple of times and then nothing happens, no file is selected for uploaded, no error in log file. I totally have no clue how to debug this error. I already tried to set **permission 777** on **localhost environmen**t but it doesn't help.

The strange thing is **product image upload** works just fine. Any other section in **admin** that has file select field still works. Only this design section has problem.

**Magento version 2.3.0** & **Php 7.2**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found someone else who reported this error. Couldn't believe Magento team can release a stable version with this obvious bug, here is the fix  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18688   &  https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ba69bfec127bed8c39c7d9e7b73d10b54449b158

Comment: ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256668/magento-2-3-0-transactional-email-logo-image-upload-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Magento version to 2.3.1, this bug is known with 2.3.0 and should be fixed when you upgrade to the newer version.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.1OpenSource.html