# Magento 2.3.0 - Transactional Email > Logo Image upload not working

Tags: magento2.3, file-upload, magento2.3.0

Running magento 2.3.0 on php 7.1

I'm trying to upload an image for

```
Content > Design: Configuration > Transactional emails > Logo Image
```

And get the following error.

> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to
>   continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again
>   later.

I've used this fix for the [header and favicon image upload](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/ba69bfec127bed8c39c7d9e7b73d10b54449b158) and it works but not for the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by a bug in magento 2.3.0, which will be fixed in 2.3.1 release.
You obviously cannot wait until then and you definitely don't want to edit core files.

ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18688

If you use composer to install/update magento 2.3.0 (if you don't, you should), you can apply a patch to the code via composer.

The process is explained here:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

For completeness, here is the patch that is needed (edited as noted in the before mentioned link)

```
diff --git a/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml b/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
index 8d4580f90c7b..bc1f36222dd6 100644
--- a/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
+++ b/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
@@ -54,7 +54,7 @@
                 <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                 <label translate="true">HTML Head</label>
             </settings>
-            <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">
+            <field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
                 <settings>
                     <notice translate="true">Not all browsers support all these formats!</notice>
                     <label translate="true">Favicon Icon</label>
@@ -151,7 +151,7 @@
                 <collapsible>true</collapsible>
                 <label translate="true">Header</label>
             </settings>
-            <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader">
+            <field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">
                 <settings>
                     <label translate="true">Logo Image</label>
                     <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
```

You want to place this in a folder `<magento root>/patches/composer`
(I named it : `image-upload.diff`)

and then adjust coposer.json accordingly

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-theme": {
                "MAGETWO-18688: Header logo image upload fix": "patches/composer/image-upload.diff"
            }
        }
    }
```

The will ensure that the fix is not wiped when you deploy/update etc

Comment: Can you, who downvoted, please explain your reasoning.

Comment: This will work for store header and favicon icon, not for the transactional email logo.

Answer (score 5):

This is the **[fix](https://github.com/chaplynsky/magento2/commit/ba325135318e2c856e5300d7139f529662679d3e)** for this issue

vendor/magento/module-email/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

```
       <collapsible>true</collapsible>
       <label translate="true">Transactional Emails</label>
       </settings>
 -     <field name="email_logo" formElement="fileUploader">
 +     <field name="email_logo" formElement="imageUploader">
       <settings>
       <notice translate="true">To optimize logo for high-resolution displays, upload an image that is 3x normal size and then specify 1x dimensions in the width/height fields below.</notice>
       <label translate="true">Logo Image</label>
```

Comment: Is this work for you properly?

Comment: Yes it worked for me.

Comment: You should not edit core files.

Comment: @ProxiBlue, You need to add this file in your custom module in this path Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

Comment: Same way you have to check other files as well

./vendor/magento/module-email/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
./vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
./vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
./vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml
./vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

Answer (score 1):

Install the 2.3.1 update and it will be fixed. any other way to fix this would be hacky and might break things after updating.